# setfacl up to root directory

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have directory `/home/user/test`. `user2` does not have any access to this directory and `/home/user` but have `rx` access to `/` and `/home` as "other" user.

I run `setfacl -m u:user2:rx /home/user/test`. But still `user2` does not have access.

Then I run `setfacl -m u:user2:rx /home/user` so now `user2` have `rx` access to all intermediate directories on `/home/user/test` path.

Is there any way to make `setfacl` check access on all directories up to root directory and apply additional permissions (I believe there is no such way) or do I need to write some bash script to iterate intermediate directories? Are there any best practices?